# Allocate total amount to a column using cumulative sum, up to another column's limit

Tags: python, conditional-statements, cumsum

Background: I am having a list of several hundred departments that I would like to allocate budget as follow:

- Each DEPT has an AMT_TOTAL budget within given number of months. They also have a monthly limit LIMIT_MONTH that they cannot exceed.
- As each DEPT plans to spend their budget as fast as possible, we assume they will spend up to their monthly limit until AMT_TOTAL runs out. The amount be forecast they will spend, given this assumption, is in AMT_ALLOC_MONTH

[image: My descriptive table]

My objective is to calculate the AMT_ALLOC_MONTH column, given the LIMIT_MONTH and AMT_TOTAL column. Based on what I've read and searched, I believe a combination of fillna and cumsum() can do the job. So far, the Python dataframe I've managed to generate is as followed:

[image: Sample Python DF]

I planned to fill the NaN using the following line:

```
table['AMT_ALLOC_MONTH'] = min((table['AMT_TOTAL'] - table.groupby('DEPT')['AMT_ALLOC_MONTH'].cumsum()).ffill, table['LIMIT_MONTH'])
```

My objective is to have the AMT_TOTAL minus the cumulative sum of AMT_ALLOC_MONTH (excluding the NaN values), grouped by DEPT; the result is then compared with value in column LIMIT_MONTH, and the smaller value is filled in the NaN cells. The process is repeated till all NaN cells of each DEPT is filled.

Needless to say, the result did not come up as I expected; the code line only works with the 1st NaN after the cell with value; subsequent NaN cells just copy the value above it. If there is a way to fix the issue, or a new & more intuitive way to do this, please help. Truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for department in table['DEPT'].unique():
    subset = table[table['DEPT'] == department]
    for index, row in subset.iterrows():
        subset = table[table['DEPT'] == department]
        cumsum = subset.loc[:index-1, 'AMT_ALLOC_MONTH'].sum()
        limit = row['LIMIT_MONTH']
        remaining = row['AMT_TOTAL'] - cumsum
        table.at[index, 'AMT_ALLOC_MONTH'] = min(remaining, limit)
```

It't not very elegant I guess, but it seems to work..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I was looking for a more panda/numpy-based, more efficient method than looping through rows, given data size of ~1 million rows.